# How to get values from catalog_product_entity_varchar?

Tags: magento, model, attributes, entity

I'm trying since hours to get some values from the table

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

with no succes.
How is this table connected to the products?

I have a product with a custom attribute "materials" and I found the values in this mentioned table.

There is no result when I try to do this:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('materials');
```

Comment: Is this dropdown attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

@credit goes to this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/how-to-get-dropdown-and-multiple-select-value-for-a-product-collection

the following should work:

`$_product->getAttributeText('some_dropdown_attr');`

Therefore only the following could be happening:

You must have mis-named your dropdown attribute
Ensure that the attribute has valid values applied on the current store view

If all else fails, there may be a problem with your attribute setup code; for instance, not visible in the frontend isn't set properly and you're using flat tables...

In that case to debug output it with the following code:

```
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('some_dropdown_attr')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

If that works check your catalog attribute configuration or disable flat indexes.

Hope this help !!